# Create session variable from mysql column parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a php session variable which should reference `"language":"ENG"` (and more specifically `ENG`) within the table column `params`.

Example: Originally I've been using a "userLanguage" column and created my php session variable like this:

```
$_SESSION['userLanguage'] = $result[0]['userLanguage'];
```

Since `"language":"ENG"` is only one part of the field's value (`{"admin_style":"","admin_language":"","language":"ENG","editor":"","helpsite":"","timezone":""}`), this obv. doesn't work anymore. Is there an easy way to pull `ENG` from language? Help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run a [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the field value.

```
$params = json_decode($result[0]['params']);
if(isset($params->language)){
    $_SESSION['userLanguage'] = $params->language;
}
```